# Date column is not set properly in open XML Excel

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy the data in excel sheet but it does not show properly it is show like ####### but I want 17-09-2016 like this.kindly suggest me what code I am write to export the excel in proper format.

Code:

```
        var rngTable2 = ws.Range("A:G");
        var rngHeaders2 = rngTable2.Range("F4:G4");
        rngHeaders2.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.General;
        rngHeaders2.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Bottom;
```

Date comes from this code:

```
Label lblpkgdate = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
string myVal1 = lblpkgdate.Text; 
ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Value = myVal1; 
index5++;
```

Comment: What is property type? datetime?

Comment: yes i want date like 17-09-2016 but it is show ##### in excel

Comment: Can you check ToString(dd-MM-yyyy);  as like myProperty.ToString(dd-MM-yyyy); where proparty to excel cell

Comment: Label lblpkgdate =(Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
            string myVal1 = lblpkgdate.Text;  
            ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString()).Value = myVal1;
          1, 01);
            index5++;

Comment: Date is come from this line how can convert it

Comment: what is this myVal1; **1, 01);**

Comment: Label lblpkgdate = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
            string myVal1 = lblpkgdate.Text;        
            ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Value = myVal1;         
            index5++;

Comment: use this pls ignored pravious

Comment: You don't right. ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
instead ToString()

Comment: can you  debug that data have in myVal1?

Comment: ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Value = myVal1;

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   on this line it will give error like this

Comment: ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString()).Value = myVal1;

Comment: ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString()).Value = myVal1; it is working fine show like ####### but i want  to 17-02-2016

Comment: can you debug that data have in myVal1? with [breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

Comment: yes i will debug the data if myVal1=17-02-2016 there is no issue in excel if myVal1=03-03-2016 it will show ###### how can avoid this

Comment: hi sir pls help me out

Comment: Why are you calling ToString() on index5 at all? presumably you're simply trying to get a cell reference equal to F5 or something? Concatenating a string value with an integer will produce a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it seems like you're trying to get a date from a label and then put this value into a load of cells within column F somewhere. I'm guessing you have this within a for loop as well seeing as you're incrementing index5. So something like this should work:

```
//Make column F a date column. Alter to a specific range if the whole column shouldn't be of date type.
Range rg = ws.Range("F:F");
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";

var lblpkgdate = (Label).gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
//Convert lblpkgdate text to DateTime object assuming format of dd/MM/yyyy to ensure it is actually a date.
DateTime pkgDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lblpkgdate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

for(int i = 1, i < YourMaxRowValue, i++)
{
    ws.Cell("F" + i).Value = pkgDate;
}
```

***NOTE*** - I've altered index5 to 'i' as this is less misleading if you're looping. I've also altered myVal1 to pkgDate as I think this is more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use NumberFormat

```
  Label lblpkgdate = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate"); 
     string myVal1 = lblpkgdate.Text;
     ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString()).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "DD-MM-YYYY";
     ws.Cell("F" + index5.ToString()).Value = myVal1;
     index5++;
```

Comment: it will gives compile time error on NumberFormat  like CloseXML does not contain defintion of NumberFormat

Comment: what is `ws` type ?

Comment: var wb = new XLWorkbook();
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Company and Vessel Details");

Comment: @SantoshKumarBind do you check?